# How to make a Wamp server installed on VPS hosting accessible by a domain name?

Tags: dns, wampserver, vps

I have a VPS hosted server with Windows Server 2003 on which I installed WAMP server, it is working and I am able to access it by localhost and modify it's contents with no problems. Also I have a domain name, say "domain-name.com". My question is how can I make it accessible on the internet by typing my owned domain name in browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite an open question, but here goes:

You'll have to set a DNS record that points to your server. Your domain registrar may offer a DNS services themselves. If they do not, and only allow you to set nameservers, have a look at http://dns.he.net (a free DNS hosting service). In the latter case, don't forget to configure the nameservers in your domain registrars panel to the HE DNS servers (ns1.he.net - ns5.he.net)!

The records you will have to add are as follows:

- An A record for www.domain-name.com, pointing to your IP
- A CNAME record for domain-name.com (often represented in a DNS panel as @), pointing to www.domain-name.com
- Optionally, MX and SPF/TXT records if you wish to use e-mail services on your domain/server (this is a whole separate subject to deal with, especially SPF records can be tricky)

Additionally, while this is not part of the question - **please don't use WAMP for public/production servers.** WAMP was made for development server setups, and it will be configured as such. If you really can't set up a HTTPd+PHP+MySQL setup yourself, then at least have a look at XAMPP, which is more suitable for live servers.